# Вопрос по интерфейсу IFormatable в C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, хочу разобраться с `IFormatable` и `IFormatProvider`

1. `ToString` у `IFormatable` принимает два параметра. Первый нужен, что бы понимать как форматировать, а второй тоже самое только более подробное и конкретное описание. Вопрос вот какой, зачем тогда первый, если второй уже все содержит? Они вообще могут друг другу противоречить. К примеру я первым параметром указал, что у цифр в качестве разделителя должна быть точка, а второй параметр(моя культура) утверждает, что должна быть запятая.
2. `IFormatProvider` у него есть метод `object` `GetFormat`(Type formatType). Вопрос, вот почему он возвращает object? Да это же можно, что угодно вернуть, почему его не сделали хотя бы обобщенным? К примеру ToString у double пытается `IFormatProvider` привести к `CultureInfo` или `NumberFormatInfo` (тогда да, он понимает к чему можно привести результат `GetFormat`). Да с чего он взял что я вообще передам ему какой из этих типов (`CultureInfo` или `NumberFormatInfo`)?

Comment: "К примеру я первым параметром указал, что у цифр в качестве разделителя должна быть точка" - точка в первом параметре это не точка в выходной строке, это указание "тут должен быть разделитель дробной части, такой, который задан во втором параметре" :)

Comment: @PashaPash Да я уже понял, это как написать у нас Русский язык, а ящик который описывает русский язык это IFormatProvider(на то он и провайдер что бы что-то предоставлять). Так же они могут быть не завязаны друг на друге как уже ответили ниже, а просто форматная строка указывает какой-то общий внешний вид, а IFormatProvider просто описывает какие-то мелкие особенности свойственные к примеру для конкретной Culture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Как сказано в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.iformattable?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks), форматная строка обычно управляет общим видом результата, в то время как провайдер формата определяет конкретные символы, используемые для этого общего вида.

Обычно в качестве провайдера формата выступает язык. Например, если вы хотите полный формат даты на немецком языке, то вы указываете в форматной строке, что вам нужна именно длинная дата, а провайдером формата выбираете `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")`.

Если бы разделения не было, вам пришлось бы передавать ещё и язык в форматной строке, и она стала бы малообозримой. Кроме того, довольно часто вы хотите *локализацию* вашего приложения, то есть вы хотите оставить одинаковую форматную строку (*смысл* вашего форматирования), и менять в зависимости от предпочтений юзера провайдер (конкретный язык, из которого берутся правила). Так что такое разделение на части имеет практический смысл.

Comment: Помогло, теперь есть понимание этого интерфейса)

Answer (score 4):

> почему он возвращает object?

Потому что он был добавлен в `.NET Framework 1.1`, когда ещё не было обобщений